# Creating an object with other object properties from DbContext in MVC EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am sorry if the answer to this question is *so* obvious, but all (and I really mean all) of my Google search results are purple, regardless of the search phrase I try to wrap around my question.

I am trying to build an MVC .NET Core 3.0 application with Code-First.
I am able to create my models, have these setup correct (I think) in my Database (Azure SQL), and using Visual Studio's standard templates to create controllers and views. I am therefore able to create each one of my model individually.

What I am trying to do is

- Create a view from where I can create a Rental-object, with link to RentalOwner and ParkingSpot.
- (Create a view from where I can see all rentals created. This is not in scope for this question)

My models

```
public class ParkingSpot
{
    public int ParkingSpotId { get; set; }
    public int ParkingSpotNumber { get; set; }
}

public class RentalOwner
{
    public int RentalOwnerId { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
}

public class Tenant
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Navn")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Rental
{
    public int RentalId { get; set; }
    public int ParkingSpotId { get; set; }
    public ParkingSpot ParkingSpot { get; set; }
    public int RentalOwnerId { get; set; }
    public RentalOwner RentalOwner { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried creating a ViewModel, to use for creation of the Rental-model and the binding to other models.

```
public class RentalCreationView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Rental Rental { get; set; }
    public int ParkingSpotId { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried with this GET and HttpPost POST Actions in my Controller.

```
    // GET: Rentals/Create
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync()
    {
        var parkingSpots = await _context.ParkingSpots.ToListAsync();
        ViewData["ParkingSpots"] = new SelectList(parkingSpots, "ParkingSpotId", "ParkingSpotNumber");
        var tenants = await _context.Tenants.ToListAsync();
        ViewData["Tenants"] = new SelectList(tenants, "TenantId", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(RentalCreationView rcw)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.RentalOwners.Add(rcw.Rental.RentalOwner);
            _context.Rentals.Add(rcw.Rental);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(rcw);
    }
```

I don't think my issue is with my View, and I guess I am missing something in either my models or in my controller.
Right now, when I try to create a Rental, the view is just loading for a couple of minutes after submit.

I have seen numerous of tutorials, read hundreds of questions and articles, and I know that I am missing some basic steps, but the code above is what I have right now (I have about 500 lines of commented out code that doesn't work).

I've spent 2 weeks trying to learn how to do this but I need some help from someone who knows what I'm trying to do.

Any relevant links, videos or documentation would be awesome.. I am really stuck deep.
Thank you

---

EDIT: I have found a solution, and to all future readers who got this page from their 1000th Google search, what I did was change a bit in the models and add this HttpPost Create in my Controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(RentalCreationView rcw)
    {
        List<ParkingSpot> parkingSpots = _context.ParkingSpots.ToList();
        List<Tenant> tenants = _context.Tenants.ToList();

        RentalOwner ro = new RentalOwner
        {
            Tenant = tenants.Find(t => t.TenantId == rcw.TenantId),
            OwnerSince = rcw.StartDate
        };

        Rental ren = new Rental
        {
            StartDate = rcw.StartDate,
            ParkingSpot = parkingSpots.Find(ps => ps.ParkingSpotId == rcw.ParkingSpotId),
            RentalOwner = ro
        };

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            _context.RentalOwners.Add(ro);
            _context.Rentals.Add(ren);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        else
        {
            var errors = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors)
                                   .Where(y => y.Count > 0)
                                   .ToList();
        }
        return View();
    }
```